# I want to initialize an Object (UserModel ) to empty object instead of a null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to initialize an Object UserModel to empty instead of null.

Reason am asking my question  is that i want to get rid of the following piece of code:

```
user = new UserModel { ISOCode= "ZAF", Gender = Gender.Male }
```

I don't want to `new` it up inside the `if` statement, I just want to assign to the empty object.

```
UserModel user = null;

string mAge = Person.PersonContext.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Gender.ToLower() == "male");

string fAge = Person.PersonContext.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Gender.ToLower() == "female");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mAge))
{
 user = new UserModel { ISOCode= "ZAF", Gender = Gender.Male }
}
 else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fAge))
{
 user = new UserModel { ISOCode = "USA",  Gender = Gender.Female} 
}
```

Comment: How many different values are defined inside the `Gender` enum? It is 2022 so I have to ask it...

Comment: I understand an its a fair question. I have the following, male, female, transgender, gender-neutral, non-binary, agender, pangender, genderqueer.

Comment: Do you have the same branching logic for all gender type?

Comment: Yes, just for this question, I just showed only the two

Comment: Then you most probably need a switch statement to do all the branching rather than having multiple else if blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `new` keyword,

```
UserModel user = new UserModel();  //Initialize with default constructor
string mAge = "";
string fAge= "";


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mAge))
  user.Gender = Gender.Male;
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fAge))
  user.Gender = Gender.Female;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a nested conditional operator?

```
var user = new UserModel 
{ 
    Gender = 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mAge) ? Gender.Male : 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fAge) ? Gender.Female : null 
};
```

I've assumed the `Gender` member of your `UserModel` is nullable.
If it is not then you should replace `null` with some fallback value, like `Gender.Unknown`